# Issue facing in installing robotframework-excellibrary with python34 version

Tags: robotframework

I tried to install from robotframework-excellibrary-master, I am getting NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined, Below is the Snapshot
[robot-framework-excellibrary_issue_facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poSGq.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use pip?

Comment: yes I tried with pip also, i am getting same error